# How to remove a certain number of digits from the front or end of an attribute field?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

Can I use the filed calculator in QGIS somehow to remove the first 4 numbers in all attribute fields in a column?

Example 16011234 -> 1234

EDIT:

Silly, I can just subtract with 16000000 in this case.

But to make it more interesting. How would I do to remove the first 2 and the 2 last numbers?

Comment: I needed to this in a dataset where my timestamps were "backwards". Actually for setting up a Time Manager seequence (thanks for that Anita). My problem where that my string had the time-value in the start of attribute and the year-value in the end of string. So I was looking for the function to delete the last 4 numbers(year). The only thing i could come up with was to make an new attribute and setting the length to 8. The result when copying the old attribute in this one is that (as wanted) that it comes without the year-value in the end. I remember doing it in Mapinfo once. Any other idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the substr() function in the field calculator

```
substr("field-name", 4, 100)
```

Comment: ...sorry for duplicate answer

Answer (score 2):

You have different possibilities

## String manipulation

```
toint( substr( tostring( 16011234 ), 5, length( tostring( 16011234 ) ) - 4 ) )
```

And for your second question:

Take the substring

- starting at position 3 ( 16**0**11234 )
- with a length of the total number of digits (8)

  - minus the first two
  - minus the last two
  - resulting in a length of 8 - 4 = 4

In the end you can convert it back to an integer

```
toint( substr( tostring( 16011234 ), 3, length( tostring( 16011234 ) ) - 4 ) )
```

## Mathematical

Question 1:

```
16011234 - round( 16011234 / 10 ^ round( log10( 16011234 ) - 3 )  ) *  10 ^ round( log10( 16011234 ) - 3 )
```

- `log10` is used to count the number of digits minus one (`log10(10)` = 1 `log10(100)` = 2...)
- `/` division in combination with `round` is used to strip away trailing digits ( `123 / 10` = 12.3, `round( 123 / 10 )` = 12 )

Question 2:
Is left as an exercise for the reader :)